# Reading a .cdb dataset on Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset which is on cdb extension I want to use it for machine learning on Python
Is there any way to read or convert this dataset? it is a large dataset and it contains digits

Answer (score 1):

Try this library

```
python-pure-cdb
```

you can build from [Source](https://github.com/dw/python-pure-cdb)

or by using pip

```
pip install pure-cdb
```

you can see the [documentation](https://python-pure-cdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-existing-cdb-files)

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to convert it to use it like MNIST dataset!?

Comment: you should construct an MNIST like dataset using the data in the cdb file , there is no such a tool to my knowledge to do that for you.

Comment: How can I see what inside the .cdb file is!? There are images inside it

Comment: you can use it like this ```reader = cdblib.Reader(data)``` than list all items to see the structure of your file by using ```reader.items() ``` it should print some arrays which represent your images.